# onPress event is not working in renderInner of reanimated-bottom-sheet

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

I use reanimated-bottom-sheet in my react native project

`bottomSheet` inside of empty page for test is work great but in main page inside the `renderInner onPress` is not working.

`Button` inside `renderHeader` in the `main.js` is not working and this `button` `import` from `nativeBase` , and I use `inputText` inside `renderInner` and again is not work but when I set 200 to size of `input` `border` and press on the `border` is work, I don't know why

this is my `test.js` page code :

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
  TextInput,
Dimensions
} from 'react-native'
import { Button,Icon } from 'native-base';

import BottomSheet from 'reanimated-bottom-sheet'
const {width, height}= Dimensions.get('window')


export default class Example extends React.Component {
    state = {
        bottomSheet:{
            opened: false,
            height: height-80
        }
    }
  renderInner = () => (
    <View style={styles.panel}>
        
      <Text style={styles.panelTitle}>San Francisco Airport</Text>
      <Text style={styles.panelSubtitle}>
        International Airport - 40 miles away
      </Text>
      <Button transparent onPress={()=>{console.log("Press")}} style={styles.panelButton}>
        <Text style={styles.panelButtonTitle}>Directions</Text>
      </Button>
      <View style={styles.panelButton}>
        <Text style={styles.panelButtonTitle}>Search Nearby</Text>
      </View>
      <Image
        style={styles.photo}
        source={require('./../../assets/image/airport-photo.jpg')}
      />
    </View>
  )

  renderHeader = () => (
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <View style={styles.panelHeader}>
        <View style={styles.panelHandle} />
        <Button 
        transparent 
        onPress={this.searchSheetClose.bind(this)}
        style={{position:'absolute',top:-20,left:-5}}
        >
            <Icon 
            type='MaterialIcons' 
            name='close' 
            style={{color:'#9f9cb9',fontSize:14,backgroundColor:'#474077',width:30,height:30,borderRadius:25,padding:8}}
            />
        </Button>
      </View>
    </View>
  )

  bs = React.createRef()

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <BottomSheet
          ref={this.bs}
          snapPoints={[ -20, this.state.bottomSheet.height, 50 ]}
          renderContent={this.renderInner}
          renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
          initialSnap={0}
        />
        
        <Button 
        transparent 
        onPress={this.searchSheetOpen.bind(this)}
        >
            <Icon 
            type='MaterialIcons' 
            name='search' 
            
            />
        </Button>
      </View>
    )
  }
  searchSheetOpen(){
    this.bs.current.snapTo(1)
    this.setState(prevState=>{
        return{
            bottomSheet:{
                ...prevState.bottomSheet,
                opened: true
            }
        }
    })
  }
  searchSheetClose(){
      console.log('ok')
    this.bs.current.snapTo(0)
    this.setState(prevState=>{
        return{
            bottomSheet:{
                ...prevState.bottomSheet,
                opened: false
            }
        }
    })
  }
}

const IMAGE_SIZE = 200

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#161e2a',
  },
  box: {
    width: IMAGE_SIZE,
    height: IMAGE_SIZE,
  },
  panelContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
  panel: {
    height: height-80,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#222e3e',

  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#222e3e',
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    paddingTop: 25,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
    borderTopRightRadius: 25,
  },
  panelHeader: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  panelHandle: {
    width: 60,
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: '#474077',
    marginBottom: 25,
  },
  panelTitle: {
    fontSize: 27,
    height: 35,
  },
  panelSubtitle: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'gray',
    height: 30,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  panelButton: {
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#318bfb',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  panelButtonTitle: {
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
  },
  photo: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 225,
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  map: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
  },
})
```

and `main.js` page :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import changeNavigationBarColor,{ showNavigationBar } from 'react-native-navigation-bar-color';
import { Container, Root, Content, Text, Footer, View, Button, Icon,Badge, Item,Input } from 'native-base';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
import BottomSheet from 'reanimated-bottom-sheet';
import { Dimensions,Image } from 'react-native'

import { main, discoverPage, HeaderStyle, searchSheet } from './../../assets/style'
import HeaderOfPage from './../../components/Header'
import FooterTabOfPage from './../../components/FooterTab'
import air from './../../assets/image/airport-photo.jpg'

const {width, height}= Dimensions.get('window')

export default class Splash extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        showNavigationBar()
    },200)
    changeNavigationBarColor('#161e2a', true)
  }

  state ={
    badge : true,
    headerTitle: null,
    leftIconesStyle: HeaderStyle.leftIconesStyleWithoutBack,
    bodyStyle: HeaderStyle.bodyWithoutBackIcon,
    searchBtn: <Button 
                transparent 
                onPress={this.serachBarAction.bind(this)}
                >
                    <Icon 
                    type='MaterialIcons' 
                    name='search' 
                    style={main.Textcolor}
                    />
                </Button>,,
    notifBtn: <Button 
              transparent 
              // onPress={this.serachBarAction.bind(this)}
              >
                {this.badge != false ? <Badge style={HeaderStyle.notifBtnBadge}></Badge> : null}
                  <Icon 
                  type='MaterialIcons' 
                  name='notifications-none' 
                  style={main.Textcolor}
                  />
              </Button>,
    bottomSheet:{
      opened: false,
      height: height-170
    }
  }
  renderInner = () => (
    <View style={searchSheet.panel}>
      
      <Text style={searchSheet.panelTitle}>San Francisco Airport</Text>
      <Text style={searchSheet.panelSubtitle}>
        International Airport - 40 miles away
      </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> {console.log('close')}} style={searchSheet.panelButton}>
        <Text style={searchSheet.panelButtonTitle} >Directions</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={searchSheet.panelButton}>
        <Text style={searchSheet.panelButtonTitle}>Search Nearby</Text>
      </View>
      <Image
        style={searchSheet.photo}
        source={air}
      />
    </View>
  )

  renderHeader = () => (
    <View style={searchSheet.header}>
      <View style={searchSheet.panelHeader}>
        <View style={searchSheet.panelHandle} />
        <Button
        transparent 
        onPress={()=> {console.log('close')}}
        style={{position:'absolute',top:-20,left:-5,zIndex:99999999999}}
        >
            <Icon 
            type='MaterialIcons' 
            name='close' 
            style={{color:'#9f9cb9',fontSize:14,backgroundColor:'#474077',width:30,height:30,borderRadius:25,padding:8}}
            onPress={()=> {console.log('close')}}
            />
        </Button>
      </View>
    </View>
  )

  bs = React.createRef()

  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={{backgroundColor:'#161e2a'}}>
        <HeaderOfPage
        bodyTitle= {this.state.headerTitle}
        leftIconesStyle={this.state.leftIconesStyle}
        bodyStyle={this.state.bodyStyle}
        searchBtn= {this.state.searchBtn}
        // backBtn= {this.state.backBtn}
        notifBtn= {this.state.notifBtn}
        />
        <Root>
          <Content style={discoverPage.content}>
            <Text style={[main.fontSize_25,main.textAlign_right,main.footerIconeColor,main.boldFontFamily]}>
              مرور کلی
            </Text>
          </Content>
          <View style={searchSheet.container}>

            <BottomSheet
              ref={this.bs}
              enabledInnerScrolling={true}
              enabledContentTapInteraction={false}
              snapPoints={[ -100, this.state.bottomSheet.height, -100 ]}
              renderContent={this.renderInner}
              renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
              initialSnap={0}
            />
            
          </View>
          <FooterTabOfPage discover={main.iconColor} iconeDiscoverName ={<Text style={[main.normalFontFamily,{fontSize:13,marginTop:5,color:'#7b7f83'}]}>مرور کلی</Text>}/>
        </Root>
      </Container>
    )
  }
  serachBarAction(){
    this.setState({
      headerTitle:null,
      leftIconesStyle:HeaderStyle.leftIconesStyleOnlySearch,
      bodyStyle: HeaderStyle.bodyAndOtherLeftIconeNull,
      notifBtn: null,
      searchBtn: <Item style={[HeaderStyle.serachBarItem,{paddingRight:10}]}>
                  <Button 
                  transparent 
                  onPress={()=>console.log('Searching...')}
                  >
                    <Icon 
                    type='MaterialIcons' 
                    name='search' 
                    style={main.Textcolor}
                    />
                  </Button>
                  <Input 
                  placeholder="جست و جو ..." 
                  placeholderTextColor={'#929292'}
                  onChangeText={this.searchSheetClose.bind(this)}
                  style={[main.normalFontFamily,main.textAlign_right,main.footerIconeColor,{fontSize: 14,}]}/>
                </Item>
    })
    this.searchSheetOpen()
  }

  searchSheetOpen(){
    this.bs.current.snapTo(1)
    this.setState(prevState=>{
        return{
            bottomSheet:{
                ...prevState.bottomSheet,
                opened: true
            }
        }
    })
  }
  searchSheetClose(){
    console.log('close')
    this.bs.current.snapTo(0)
    this.setState(prevState=>{
        return{
            bottomSheet:{
                ...prevState.bottomSheet,
                opened: false
            }
        }
    })
    this.setState({
      leftIconesStyle: HeaderStyle.leftIconesStyleWithoutBack,
      bodyStyle: HeaderStyle.bodyWithoutBackIcon,
      searchBtn: <Button 
                  transparent 
                  onPress={this.serachBarAction.bind(this)}
                  >
                      <Icon 
                      type='MaterialIcons' 
                      name='search' 
                      style={main.Textcolor}
                      />
                  </Button>,
      notifBtn: <Button 
                transparent 
                >
                  {this.badge != false ? <Badge style={HeaderStyle.notifBtnBadge}></Badge> : null}
                    <Icon 
                    type='MaterialIcons' 
                    name='notifications-none' 
                    style={main.Textcolor}
                    />
                </Button>,
    })
  }
}
```

`stye.js` :

```
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'
const {width, height}= Dimensions.get('window')

export const searchSheet =  EStyleSheet.create({
    
    container: {
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor: '#161e2a',
        marginLeft:20,
        marginRight:20,
        zIndex:9999999999999,
    },
    box: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
    },
    panelContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
    },
    panel: {
        height: height-80,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#222e3e',
    },
    header: {
        backgroundColor: '#222e3e',
        shadowColor: '#000000',
        paddingTop: 25,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
        borderTopRightRadius: 25,
        zIndex:99999999999999
    },
    panelHeader: {
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    panelHandle: {
        width: 60,
        height: 8,
        borderRadius: 4,
        backgroundColor: '#474077',
        marginBottom: 25,
    },
    panelTitle: {
        fontSize: 27,
        height: 35,
    },
    panelSubtitle: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: 'gray',
        height: 30,
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
    panelButton: {
        padding: 20,
        borderRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#318bfb',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginVertical: 10,
    },
    panelButtonTitle: {
        fontSize: 17,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'white',
    },
    photo: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 225,
        marginTop: 30,
    },
    map: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
    },
    closeBtn:{
        position:'absolute',
        top:-20,
        left:-5
    },
    closeBtnIcon:{
        color:'#9f9cb9',
        fontSize:14,
        backgroundColor:'#474077',
        width:30,
        height:30,
        borderRadius:25,
        padding:8
    }
})
```

Comment: It can be a problem with the reanimated bottom sheet. I had a similar problem when I was using a `RectButton` from react-native-gesture-handler inside `react-native-modal`, and the simplest solution was to use a TouchableOpacity button instead of RectButton or a button from another lib that I don't remember the name.

Comment: @RoniCastro I tried hard and understood that when it slideUp on the page content does not work. In fact, a trace of the content of the page is overlaid on it (sorry my english is bad)

Comment: This is the comment https://github.com/osdnk/react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet/issues/219#issuecomment-625894292

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the bottomSheet add --> enabledContentGestureInteraction={false}

Below is the bottom sheet which I implemented. It works

```
  <BottomSheet
    ref={sheetRef}
    snapPoints={[200, 0]}
    initialSnap={1}
    enabledGestureInteraction={true}
    enabledContentGestureInteraction={false}
    renderHeader={renderHead}
    renderContent={renderContent}
  />
```

Comment: OOPs it's not a perfect solution, because if you have a scrollable view then it's bad solution. It stops scrollable functionality. Please see the below answer for a perfect solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using this https://github.com/osdnk/react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet then see the solution -

You will need to introduce `enabledContentTapInteraction={false}` by default it is **true**. If you are you TouchableInterface or onPress event then use the above line in the below code -

```
<BottomSheet 
            ref={bs}
            snapPoints={['45%', 0]}
            renderContent={renderContent}
            renderHeader={renderHeader}
            initialSnap={1}
            // callbackNode={fall}
            enabledGestureInteraction={true}
            enabledContentTapInteraction={false}
            style={{backgroundColor: Color.bgWhite}}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from setting `enabledContentTapInteraction={false}`, using the `onPressOut` event instead of `onPress` also worked for me. Although for components which only expose the `onPress` event, setting `enabledContentTapInteraction={false}` works.